# Nested loops to find max

Tags: c++, nested, max

I am coding a program to find the maximum of an equation over an interval given by the user. When I compile the code instead of outputting the maximum it gives me this

Please enter the first number of the interval to be checked: 
Please enter the last number of the interval to be checked: 
Please enter the desired initial step size: 
sh: PAUSE: command not found

I figure the problem has to do with my loops, but I'm not sure how to rectify the situation.
Here's my code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int a, b, delta, x, y;
    int max = 0;


    cout <<"Please enter the first number of the interval to be checked: " << endl;
    cin >> a;
    cout << "Please enter the last number of the interval to be checked: " << endl;
    cin >> b;
    cout << "Please enter the desired initial step size: " << endl;
    cin >> delta;

    for(x = a; x <= b; x = x+delta)
    {
        y = pow(x, 2)-7*x-18;
        if (y > max)
        {
            max = y;
            cout <<"The maximum over the interval from " << a <<" to " << b <<" is " << max;
        }
        else
        {
            delta= delta/2;
        }
        if (delta <  pow( 10, -6))
        {
            break;
        }
    }      

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: why do you need to use system pause?

Comment: I suppose that it's not really necessary. I'll get rid of it. That doesn't help with whatever is wrong with my loops though.

Comment: Can you clarify what your problem is? [it doesn't do _nothing_](http://ideone.com/Xw7ffq). Just move the printing of max outside of the loop...

Comment: You should consider changing your algorithm as I see a few mathematical flaws. For example, the function could be completely negative and 0 which is never attained would be the max. (this is easily fixed by setting the first y value to equal the max). Another is let's say the quadratic function is x^2-4x+5 and the interval is 0 to 10 with step size 1. The max value clearly occurs at 10 but your program detects that at x=0, y=5. It's the new max and delta is halved  and x approaches but never reaches 1 and all y values for those are less than 5. Consider differentiation

Comment: There is no max for this equation.

Comment: You should consider using newton's method to get the roots and you know that the max either occurs at a root and/or at the endpoints

Comment: "loops" - there is only one loop, and it has numerous problems. Unless I'm mistaken your assignment is to implement a descending partition algorithm that zero's in on an ever shrinking partition within a range, where each redux is using a more confined segment and an ever decreasing step-delta. When you're reached a delta smaller than 0.000001, stop and display whatever you found. If that is the intent your code barely scratches the surface of doing this. You need to rethink your algorithm, and I strongly advise making some parameterized functions to assist in this.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code it seems like that the value of delta should be in float as you are recursively dividing it by 2. Your pow (10,-2) doesn't do any useful comparison for that matter. even after everything it doesn't throw me that pause error. I ran it on VS 12 (C++11).